# Openlayers 3 improving vector layer performance

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a vector layer which is county boundaries for all counties in the US.  When I add this layer to the map, the map becomes very slow when zooming in and moving around on the map when I am zoomed out to a certain extent, but performs Okay when I am zoomed in.  I believe this is because of how much detail that is being drawn with all the county lines when zoomed out.  Does anyone know of a way to force openlayers to draw a less detailed version of the vector layer when I am zoomed out to a certain extent?  Also any other ideas to improve performance with detailed vector layers like this would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you try simplify your boundaries with https://github.com/mbostock/topojson?

Comment: How do you load your Vectors? I had the same problem with vectors I loaded from an PostGIS DB. I fixed it by refreshing the vectors on each zoom and using ST_SIMPLIFY to simplify the vecotrs for the different zoom levels.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an image layer with an image-vector source.

Here's an example:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/image-vector-layer.html